# Trying to use paths.ortho in overleaf by importing tikz-ext

Tags: tikz-arrows, overleaf

I am trying to use `paths.orthos` package in [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qfgmrjrkhckc) and by importing [tikz-ext](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en) and I am failing. I don't know if its a right a way to import `paths.orthos` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-ext}

\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.node-families}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,-latex]
\draw[help lines,-] (-.25, -.25) grid (5.25, 3.25);
\draw (0, 0) -|-[distance= .5cm] ++(2, 1);
\draw (0, 2) -|-[distance=-.5cm] ++(2, 1);
\tikzset{xshift=3cm}
\draw (2, 1) -|-[distance= .5cm] ++(-2, -1);
\draw (2, 3) -|-[distance=-.5cm] ++(-2, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Error:

> LaTeX Error: File `tikz-ext.sty' not found.

Comment: Overleaf used an TL2022 from something like June or July 2022. `tikz-ext` was published in August.

Comment: ... and even if the package is installed, you can't load it via `\usepackage{tikz-ext}`. You just need the libraries.

Comment: Makes sense. I just wanted to use `paths.orthos`, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You could download the zip file from ctan and then manually upload all the files to your project.

Comment: (I did not test if tikz-ext is compatible with the older packages from overleaf)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I downloaded the zip from ctan, unzipped it and uploaded it to overleaf. It didn't work: https://www.overleaf.com/6374412713pgtwcgtryjnk

Comment: Check now. As said above, `\usepackage{tikz-ext}` is wrong, you should only load the libraries. And place the files in the same folder as your main file so latex can find them.